# Mocking promise chain function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing test case for angular controller. I faced one issue while mocking service API call. 
My controller api call is:

```
 this.testMe = User.getDetails().then(function (response) {
            this.user = response.data;

        }.bind(this), function (response) {
            console.log("error function mocking")
        });
```

In my test case i want to mock this service "**User**"'s method "**getDetails**". So my test case mocking is like this:

```
   this.getCurrentUserDetails = function () {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve({data: 'test'});
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
```

When I run the test case it gives me error like this :

> 'undefined' is not a function (near '...}.bind(this), function (re...')

As in my API call there is **bind()** function, which the controller is not able to find. So how can I mock the service with bind() function also.

Comment: Using phantomJS to run the tests? There's no `Function.prototype.bind` ~ https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522

Comment: Yes i am using phantomJS. I don't know about "Function.prototype.bind"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Function.prototype.bind` in your controller (the `}.bind(this)` bit). [PhantomJS 1.x has not implemented `bind()`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522) so you cannot use it in the test runner.

Your options are...

1. Install [bind-polyfill](https://github.com/kdimatteo/bind-polyfill) (preferably in your Bower `devDependencies`) and include it in your `karma.conf.js` files
2. Alias `this`

   ```
   var ctrl = this;
   this.testMe = User.getDetails().then(function (response) {
       ctrl.user = response.data;
   }, function (response) {
       console.log("error function mocking")
   });
   ```
3. If you're using underscore / lodash, try the `_.bind` function instead

   ```
   this.testMe = User.getDetails().then(_.bind(function (response) {
       ctrl.user = response.data;
   }, this)
   ```
4. Use a different browser in your `karma.conf.js` file

   ```
   browsers : ['Chrome'],

   plugins : [
       'karma-chrome-launcher',
       'karma-jasmine'
   ]
   ```